# How to add gaussian noise (10%) to a set of datapoints

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

i have a set of 100 point (2-dimensional, x-y). I have to add to each x-coordinate a 10% gaussian noise. The 10% is referred to each x-value. I've found around this line of code:

```
noisy_data = exact_data
relativeError = 0.1
noisy_data[:,0] = [ np.random.normal(loc=value, scale=abs(relativeError*value)) for value in noisy_data[:,1]]
```

I'm not sure this is the right way to do that. Do you know if it is correct? If not, is there a function that can do it properly?

Comment: what are mean and variance of the guassian noise?

Comment: The excercise doesn't specify that.

Comment: if first column is x and second column is y: 
`noisy_data = [np.random.normal(value, abs(relativeError*value)) for value in exact_data[:,0]]; noisy_data = np.c_[noisy_data, exact_data[:, 1]]`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the y values don't matter. Also, there's no need to iterate over each element.

```
noisy_data = exact_data.copy()
noisy_data[:, 0] += np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=abs(relativeError*noisy_data[:, 0]))
```